Online updating of $t$-value for simple linear regression
Suppose I am regressing a dependent variable $y$ onto a single independent variable $x$ using a simple ordinary least squares regression model $y = \beta_1 x + \beta_0$.  Suppose I start with $n$ data points $(x_1,y_1), \ldots (x_n, y_n)$ and I fit my regression to obtain
$$
\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{s_{xy}}{s^2_x}
$$
and
$$
\hat{\beta_0} = \bar{y} - \hat{\beta_1} \bar{x}
$$
Now suppose I have a stream of new incoming data $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}),\ldots$.
I know how to compute the terms $\bar{x}, \bar{y},s^2_x,s^2_y,s_{xy}$ for the new dataset, augemented with the newly arriving points, efficiently -- namely, I can update all of these quantities in constant time, leveraging my knowledge of them from the first $n$ datapoints.  As such, I also know how to efficiently update the quantities $\hat{\beta_1},\hat{\beta_0},r^2$.
I would like to know if there is any clever trickery that allows me to also efficiently update my $t$-score, namely
$$
t = \frac{\hat{\beta_1}}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{\sum{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}}}
$$
where $s$ is the unbiased estimator for the underlying constant standard deviation $\sigma$ in our error that we assume in the model given by
$$
s = \frac{1}{n-2} \sum{(y_i - \hat{y_i})^2}
$$
The primary issue to my eye is that all of the $\hat{y_i}$ values change when we add a new data point, and as such they are all needed in the recomputation of $s$.  Is there a way around this?  Can I update the $t$-score (or equivalently $s$) in constant time?
Assuming a negative answer, I suppose that some control over how much the $t$-score can change would be useful.  I could derive this, but I would also appreciate any literature pointers.

your t value formula seems to be missing the square?

Not an answer, but if you have so much data that you need to do this... you are probably doing it wrong (practical significance, multiple testing, ...)

@wei Thank you - fixed!

Define n, sx, sy, sxx, sxy, syy
\begin{align}s_x & = \sum{x_i},\\s_y &= \sum{y_i}, \\s_{xx} &= \sum{(x_i \times x_i)}, \\s_{yy} &= \sum{(y_i \times y_i)}, \\s_{xy} & = \sum{(x_i \times y_i)}\end{align}
so $\beta_1$ is
$$ \beta_1 = \frac {\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})(y_{i}-{\bar {y}})}{\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})^{2}}=\frac {{n} \times {s_{xy}} - s_x \times  s_y}{n \times s_{xx} - s_x \times s_x}$$
$s_{\widehat {\beta }}$ is
$$\begin{align} s_{\widehat {\beta }} &= {\sqrt {\frac {{\frac {1}{n-2}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}{\widehat {\varepsilon }}_{i}^{\,2}}{\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})^{2}}}} \\&= {\sqrt {\frac {\sigma _{\epsilon }^{\,2}}{\sigma _{x }^{\,2}{(n - 2)}}}} \\&= {\sqrt {\frac {(1-\rho _{xy}^{2})\sigma _{y}^{2}}{\sigma _{x }^{\,2}{(n - 2)}}}} \\&= {\sqrt {\frac {\sigma_{y}^{2} - {\rho_{xy}^{2}}{\sigma_{y}^{2}} }{\sigma_{x}^{2}{(n - 2)}}}} \\&= {\sqrt {\frac {\sigma_{y}^{2} - {\beta_1^2}{\sigma_{x}^{2}} }{\sigma_{x}^{2}{(n - 2)}}}} \\&= \frac{s_{yy} - s_y \times s_y / n - \beta_1 ^ 2 \times (s_{xx} - s_x \times s_x / n)}{(n - 2) \times (s_{xx} - s_x \times s_x / n)}\end{align}$$
you can check by simulate data
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)

N = 100

x = rnorm(N)
y = 0.10 + 0.30 * x + rnorm(N)
df = tibble(x, y)

# sufficient statistics
n = nrow(df)
sx = sum(df$x)
sy = sum(df$y)
sxy = sum(df$x * df$y)
sxx = sum(df$x * df$x)
syy = sum(df$y * df$y)


mod = summary(lm(y ~ x, df))$coef

# b1
mod['x', 'Estimate'] # true value
b1 = (n * sxy - sx * sy) / (n * sxx - sx * sx) # from sufficient statistics
b1

# s1
mod['x', 'Std. Error'] # true value
sqrt((syy - sy * sy / n - b1 ^ 2 * (sxx - sx * sx / n)) / ((n - 2) * (sxx - sx * sx / n))) # from sufficient statistics

[1] 0.4387948
[1] 0.4387948
[1] 0.1096026
[1] 0.1096026


Thank you for this wei!!  Just to make sure I understand your notation: $\sigma_x$ is the unbiased estimator (with the Bessel correction) of the sample variance of $X$?  And $\rho_{xy}$ is similarly the unbiased estimator of the correlation between $x$ and $y$?

$\sigma^2$ is population variances(without the Bessel correction): this does not affect the result (old formula had some errors and now has been fixed), since it appears in both the numerator and the denominator and cancels

Thank you Wei, sorry for my misunderstanding and thank you for your response!

Also I just noticed today, $t = \sqrt{n-2} r / \sqrt{1-r^2}$ which I suppose also is an answer to my question.

But your answer gives an efficient way of updating $s_{\hat{\beta}}$ and hence not only updating $t$, but also the confidence interval for $\beta_1$. :-)
